# Java convert from String array to short array?

Tags: java

hello I have a commaseparated list of string and put into an array.

I ultimately need them as a list of shorts, but the only way I know how to do that is get them as an array of shorts then do `array.asList()`

```
String[] stringArray= commaSeparatedString.split("\\s*,\\s*");
```

How can I get that to an array of shorts so I can throw in a list?

THanks

Comment: Do you know about `Short.parseShort`? Use that in a loop.

Answer (score 5):

Well presumably you just need to parse each element. But why not just add them to an `ArrayList<Short>`?

```
List<Short> shortList = new ArrayList<Short>(stringArray.length);
for (int i = 0; i < stringArray.length; i++) {
    shortList.add(Short.valueOf(stringArray[i]));
}
```

(Note that you can't have a list of a primitive type, as Java generics don't support primitive type arguments.)

Answer (score 0):

After the splitting you parse each string to the desired type for example Short.parseShort(element)