# Java difference between Short.parseShort and Short.valueOf

Tags: java, short

I have recently stumbled upon [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19392178/java-convert-from-string-array-to-short-array) on Stack Overflow where one person suggests using Short.parseShort(String s) and another Short.valueOf(String s).

I have tried both myself, and I found no difference in functionality and the [official Documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Short.html#parseShort(java.lang.String)) didn't really help me either:

> **Short.parseShort:**
>   Parses the string argument as a signed decimal short. The characters in the string must all be decimal digits, except that the first character may be an ASCII minus sign '-' ('\u002D') to indicate a negative value or an ASCII plus sign '+' ('\u002B') to indicate a positive value. The resulting short value is returned, exactly as if the argument and the radix 10 were given as arguments to the parseShort(java.lang.String, int) method.
>
> **Short.valueOf:**
>   Returns a Short object holding the value given by the specified String. The argument is interpreted as representing a signed decimal short, exactly as if the argument were given to the parseShort(java.lang.String) method. The result is a Short object that represents the short value specified by the string.

Both accept the additional Parameter `radix`, and both throw a `NumberFormatException`.

They seem to be identical, but if that is the case, why do both exist?

Comment: The biggest difference is that `parseShort` returns a primitive `short`, while `valueOf` returns an instance of the wrapper class `java.lang.Short`.

Comment: One returns a primitive `short`, the other returns a boxed `Short`

Comment: Also, unless you have a good reason not to, you should probably be using `int`/`Integer` instead.

Comment: Thanks for all the answers (and sorry for not seeing the Duplicate). @4castle I am using short because I want to force my coworkers to use appropiate values (they are read from a config, therefore the String conversion)

Comment: @CrowleyAstray I'll trust that you know what constitutes appropriate values. You might be interested in this question: [Why are so many of the numbers I see signed when they shouldn't be?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/352896/226788). The answers discuss why `int` is often the best choice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`valueOf` is using `parseShort` internally and additionally wraps the value in a boxed type `Short`:

```
public static Short valueOf(String s, int radix)
    throws NumberFormatException {
    return valueOf(parseShort(s, radix));
}
```